# Cursor freezes inside textarea when using in Salesforce 1 App

Tags: mobile, ios, inputtext

I am facing a weird problem when using visualforce page in Salesforce 1 Application. When I try to copy and paste the data into text-area box, cursor freezes and after that can't type or paste any text into it. Is this a known issue or is there anything that I have to change in my code?

Below is the code snippet for the same:

Please revert for more information.

Thanks in Advance!!

Thanks,
Nagaraj

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T5l1AAC).

> Some of our customers are reporting issues with Visualforce Pages
>   freezing in Salesforce1 iOS after making a long press to activate
>   iOS's magnifying glass functionality. i.e. Copy / Paste, Selection
>
> **Update as of 1/27/2015**  This has been verified as a Bug on the Apple side. Salesforce plans to move to the wkwebview later this year
>   **SAFEHARBOR** However this may not resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, I'll make sure to adhere to this in future. Also fixed the link to point to correct URL

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add some, took a whole 5 seconds. Doing so provides some info to others, without requiring them to navigate elsewhere.

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke - Thanks! As I mentioned, I'll adhere to that in future

Comment: The great thing about edit buttons is that they allow you to go back into the past to restore and improve it :-). Keep in mind these questions and answers remain online for a very long time, and it's always relevant to improve their content and accuracy when possible.